# After self addition the object becomes None...?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

Try this simple code (MCVE):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.v = val

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Foo(self.v + other.v)

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        print('before iadd v = {}'.format(self.v))
        self.v = (self + other).v
        print('after iadd v = {}'.format(self.v))

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Foo.__repr__({})'.format(self.v)

a = Foo(3)
b = Foo(5)
a += b
print('Now a is {}'.format(a))
```

The output is

```
before iadd v = 3
after iadd v = 8
Now a is None
```

I suppose `a += b` should modify `a` in-place (and that's what I wrote in `Foo.__iadd__()`. That confused me for a long time. I expected that the last line should be

```
Now a is Foo.__repr__(8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you return nothing in the `__iadd__` method. Try returning self.

Comment: `def __add__(self, other):
        return Foo(self.v + other.v)` isn't it a *return*?

Comment: @iBug: Wrong method.

Comment: @iBug do it for __iadd__ method

Comment: But, shouldn't `__iadd__` modify objects **in-place**?

Comment: @iBug It does. But it modify existing value with the returned one. Since you return nothing, result becomes None.

Comment: To add to this the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) do say these methods attempt to do the operation in place and return the result.